# Unity Postprocessing Warning Message

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, post-processing

Changed camera's Viewport because of LetterBox in Unity.

After building Android, the following warning is displayed every frame in PostProcessing.

2023-12-08 14:17:47.603 24774 24796 Warn Unity When used with builtin render pipeline, Postprocessing package expects to be used on a fullscreen Camera.

Although the code has been commented out, the code will be restored to its original state.

Due to the LetterBox issue, the Viewport could not be kept at 1,0.

Comment: What is a letterbox? And are you sure the solution would be to modify the camera's Viewport in the first place? Regarding the change being reset: That's because it is a package .. if you want to modify a package you can do so by copying it from `Library/PackagesCache/PACKAGE` into `Packages/PACKAGE` .. this way it converts into an *embedded* package and is fully modifiable... if you know what you are doing ;)